# Is it possible to know when some data is available for being searched in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm implementing a software in which data is sent to some web server, stored in an Elasticsearch and then queried right away. I know that Elasticsearch is a NoSQL following BASE (Basically Available, soft State, eventual consistency) principles which means there's no guarantee when your data will be available for searching.

That's why when I query for the data just being added to Elasticsearch, I have to wait for some time before it is found. Right now all I can do is to implement a polling mechanism to detect when data is completely applied. It is worth mentioning that if I'm using `_id` to retrieve a document, it is found right away. But if I'm searching for it using some type of Elasticsearch query (like `term` or `query_string`), it will take a while before the document is found.

So my question is: Is there a cheaper way to detect when data is completely indexed in Elasticsearch?

Comment: I think it could help https://www.elastic.co/blog/refreshing_news

Comment: That's great, thanks. Would you please post it as an answer so I can flag it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is done by the Refresh API, this API does not provide a way to know when the indexed data is available. But the folks of elastic are working in a hack to let the request wait for a refresh.

I think should be better if you take a look here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/refreshing_news

This post have a good overview of the issues and the stuffs that they are working to improve.

Hope it help :D